# Generic hyperplane and transversal intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

I'm trying to solve an exercise I.7.7 in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry:

> **7.7.** Let $Y$ be a variety of dimension $r$ and degree $d>1$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Let $P \in Y$ be a nonsingular point. Define $X$ to be
>   the closure of the union of all lines $\overline{PQ}$, where $Q \in Y,
> > Q\neq P$.
>
> (a) Show that $X$ is a variety of dimension $r+1$.
>
> (b) Show that $deg X < d$.

I've proved (a); it follows from the fact that there is a dominant rational map from the projective cone over $Y$ to $X$.

However, to prove (b), I'm stuck.

I found that it suffices to prove the following:

> Let us consider the set $(\mathbb{P}^n)^*$ of all hyperplanes in
>   $\mathbb{P}^n$ as the projective $n$-space $\mathbb{P}^n$ with its
>   Zariski topology.
>
> Let $W$ be the set of all hyperplanes containing $P$. Then W is a
>   hyperplane in $(\mathbb{P}^n)^*$.
>
> Then, for any (closed) variety $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ which contains
>   $P$ and is nonsingular at $P$, the set
>
> $$\{ H\in W: \mbox{For every irreducible component $Z$ of } Y\cap H, i(Y,H;Z) = 1. \} $$
>
> contains a nonempty open subset of $W$.

Now $i(Y,H;Z)$ is the intersection multiplicity of $Y$ and $H$ along $Z$, i.e., the length of the $\mathcal{O}_Z$-module $\mathcal{O}_Z / (I(Y)+I(H))\mathcal{O}_Z$, where $\mathcal{O}_Z$ is the local ring of $\mathbb{P}^n$ at $Z$.

How can I prove this? Thanks.

**Edited**: I found that if the ideal $I(Y)+I(H)$ is a radical ideal, then $i(Y,H;Z) = 1$ for all $Z$.

Comment: do you know that the degree of a variety can be expressed as the generic number of intersection points that it has with a linear subspace if complementary dimension?

Comment: Yes, and thus the claim is true for $n=2$. But I don't know how to prove it for higher dimension.